# How to prevent form submission when hitting enter

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

I have a form, and i have a field called systemParameters which i want to specify many values which are saved in an array on pressing enter.

The problem is at the same time when pressing enter the form gets submitted.

Which way is the best to submit the form in this case?

My initial thought have been to disable submit button until all fields are full, but when i fill all fields, because i add several values to the systemParameters field, it will cause the form to submit at some point.

Here is a plunker of what i have so far done.

https://plnkr.co/edit/dHJf8QEhhvU5LupdDcmX?p=info

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, ControlGroup, AbstractControl, Validators, Control} from "angular2/common";

@Component({
    selector: 'parameters-form',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `
      <h1>Parameters Form</h1>
      <p>{{ arr }}</p>
      <form [ngFormModel]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)" class="ui form">

        ...

          <div class="field">
            <label for="systemParameters">System Parameters</label>
            <input type="number"
                   id="systemParameters"
                   placeholder="systemParameters Param"
                   [ngFormControl]="systemParameters"
                   (keypress)="addToArray($event, systemParameters.value)">

            <button type="button" (click)="addToArray(systemParameters.value)">Add</button>

          </div>

          ...

        <button type="submit" class="ui button">Submit</button>
      </form>
    `
})
export class ParametersForm {
  myForm: ControlGroup;
  systemParameters: AbstractControl;
  arr: number[];

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({
      "realisations" : [""],
      "numConstSteps" : [""],
      "timeHorizon": [""],
      "continuationStep" : [""],
      "continuationStepSign" : [""],
      "numberOfModelParameters" : [""],
      "systemParameters" : [],
      "param" : [""],
      "netLogoFile" : [""],
      "numberOfModelVariables" : [""],
      "restrictOperator" : [""],
      "liftOperator" : [""],
      "xInitial" : [""]

    });
    this.arr = [];
    this.systemParameters = this.myForm.controls["systemParameters"];
  }
  addToArray(event,value: any): void {
    if (event.charCode == 13){
      this.arr.push(value);
      this.arr = this.arr.slice();
      (<Control>this.systemParameters).updateValue("");
    }
  }
  onSubmit(form: any): void {
    console.log(this.arr);
    form.systemParameters = this.arr;
    console.log("your submitted value:", form)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a smart solution but it seems to work

```
<form #f=ngForm [ngFormModel]="myForm" (keydown.enter)="false" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)" class="ui form">
  ...  
<button type="button" (click)="f.ngSubmit.emit(null)" class="ui button">Submit</button>
```

See also https://plnkr.co/edit/sekWZHOXlyQOSMoRuAUz?p=preview (stripped down a bit from your template)

Comment: ah seems its not working please check the plunker updated it!

Comment: doesn't work either. I mean the submit does not work with enter which is what i want, but then also my field that i want to work with pressing enter does not work either. EDIT: updated my plunker to reflect latest changes

Comment: Your question says you don't want the form to submit on enter. What should happen on enter?

Comment: I think you missed this part of my post `I have a form, and i have a field called systemParameters which i want to specify many values which are saved in an array on pressing enter.`